# Onclick() function on working

Tags: javascript

all! I am having a problem using the a simple onclick method.  Kindly please help me out.  Here is that code... When i click on the button nothing really happens.

```
window.onload=initall();
var xhr = false;

function initall(){

    var btn=document.getElementById('btn');

    btn.onclick=alert('hi');
}



<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="testjs.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" required name="id">
<input type="button"  id="btn" value="send">
<div id="result"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please be sure to use proper grammar, spelling, capitalization, etc. where possible.  It makes it easier for others to understand your intent and help you.

Answer (score 1):

Onclick should be a function, not a statement. Try

```
btn.onclick=function(){ 
  alert('hi');
}
```

Comment: Did you just copy/paste, or fixed the other onclick as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload=initall();
```

**calls** the function `initall` and assigns the *return value* of `initall` as event handler. That is, `initall` is executed immediately and not when the `load` event is triggered.
 Similar for `btn.onclick=alert('hi');`. But in both cases, the return value is not a function.

You have to assign **functions** to those properties, which are then being called when the event occurs.

```
function initall(){
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

    btn.onclick = function() { // creates and assigns the function at once
        alert('hi');
    };
}

window.onload = initall; // assign the function reference, no `()`.
```

I recommend to [read the excellent tutorials at quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) to learn about event handling and of course the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) for the JavaScript basics.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this for onclick javascript function call   


    function initall(){

        var btn=document.getElementById('btn');

        btn.onclick=alert('hi');
    }
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="testjs.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <input type="text" required name="id">
    <input type="button"  id="btn" value="send" onclick="javascript:initall();">
    <div id="result"></div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/uxfD4/

the onclick assignment accepts a function.  What your code did was evaluate alert('hi'), returning null.