# Only inline handlers works

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, dom-events

On my application only inline handlers works.

This is part of my Javascript function

```
function onDeviceReady() {
        alert('ready');
        document.querySelector('#idCpf').onkeypress = alert('keypress');
        document.getElementById("idCpf").onclick=alert("click");
     }
```

And this is my part of my html code

```
 <input type="tel" autocomplete="on" id="idCpf" onblur="alert('onblur')" placeholder="Seu CPF" required>
```

On `onDeviceReady` function only the first alert works, and `onkeypress` and `onclick` show me an alert when the function `onDeviceReady` without pressing, click or blur the input. But my code only works when I use inline handlers, like on `input type.... onblur="alert('onblur')"`.

What is my problem?

Comment: You are calling `alert` and assig the return value of `alert` to the properties, not a function. You have to assign a function to those properties.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Onclick() function on working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270046/onclick-function-on-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('#idCpf').onkeypress = alert('keypress');
```

calls the `alert('keypress');` and assigns the return value of `alert('keypress');` as event handler.

`alert('keypress');` is executed immediately and not when the event is triggered.

To assign event handler you must do,

```
document.querySelector('#idCpf').onkeypress = function () { alert('keypress') };
document.getElementById("idCpf").onclick= function () { alert("click") };
```